# Java - Math.asin() only returns 0

Tags: java, math

I've been struggling with Math.asin() for a while.

```java
System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(1 / 2)));
```

This very simple line of code pretty much sums up my desperation: The result should be 30°, however, I only get 0.0 as a result. Its not just these numbers, no matter which numbers I use, the result is 0.0.
My question is, is this a known bug of Java, or am I missing something?

Bonus Information:
I need asin() to calculate the angle between the centerpoints of two objects in my game.

Comment: Note, you are doing integer division.

Comment: `1/2 == 0`, you're dividing integers which results in integer. Try `1f/2`

Comment: Oh my god. I'll never get used to that. Thank you, that's the solution.

Comment: @Solo if that solved your question please remember to «tick» the answer, or answer the question yourself, so others can benefit from same question

Answer (score 0):

You’re doing integer division, please add a decimal point in the end of each number like this:

```
System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(1.0/2.0)))
```